# Magento Product Import With Multiple Images IN ONE ROW

Tags: image, magento, import, row

Can i upload multiple image in the same column or separate column and not in separate  row.

I have a csv file with many product exported from another store and images' names are in separate column and each next row has a different product.So i would have to  insert new rows after every product manually if i want more images under _media_image

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Magmi? The image attributes processor will import multiple images http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-image-attributes-processor/. Lots of help around via google.